# Create link (url) to the full node from a Solr view (search results) with rewrite results

Tags: 8, uri, navigation, search

In `admin/config/search/search-api/index/default_index/fields` I added URI field.

But how can I create a link to the full content? In the view, when I click on *Add fields* I am able to select: `URI (indexed field)    Index Default index A URI where the item can be accessed`

But in the field settings, when I select:

```
Link this field to its item
Display this field as a link to its original entity or item.
```

It doesn't become a link? How do I create a link to the full content in a Solr view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by Checking Retrieve result data from Solr in the solr server configuration (Advanced tab). After checking this box I am able to use {{ url }} in my view.